# Adding texture (an image) when loading with ObjectLoader

Tags: three.js

I'm using ObjectLoader to load my scene (exported using ObjectExporter). How can I apply textures to my objects while loading?

Comment: Have you tried this example?
http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_obj.html

Comment: I know about OBJLoader, which is to load .obj to Three JS. What I want is, I exported my scene using ObectExporter, and trying to import it back using ObjectLoader. Doing so, I'm losing my textures on objects. The basic idea behind this is to save game progress, and reload saved game. Any help?

Comment: My export code var result = JSON.stringify(new THREE.ObjectExporter().parse( scene ));

Comment: My import code var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
loader.load('my_exported_scene.js', function (object) {  console.log('adding object to scene');
 scene.add(object);
});

Answer (score 2):

Use ObjectLoader to load the object, and then use it's geometry to create a mesh with a loaded texture:

```
var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
    loader.load("models/ship.json",
        function (obj) {
            var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
                      map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('models/textures/ship.jpg')});
            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(obj.geometry, material);
            scene.add(mesh);
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

OBJMTLLoader.js

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
loader.load("../assets/models/shark/Shark.obj", "../assets/models/shark/Shark.mtl", function (shark) {
```