# three.js Materials are not working after exported using ObjectExporter

Tags: three.js

am exporting my models using `ObjectExporter`, my code is follows

```
exporter = new THREE.ObjectExporter;
    var obj = exporter.parse(globalObject);
    var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
    console.log(json);
```

i can get the json exported data successfully, but after load it using `ObjectLoader` the Geometry only loading materials are not loading, am loading my saved model by following code

```
 var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
loader.load("savedjson.json",function ( obj ) {
  scene.add( obj );
  console.log(obj);
});
```

any clue to get materials work with the `ObjectExporter`?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I have a first attempt at a workaround(but it needs to be improved for sure). What I do is, after loading the object, I traverse the model

```
    loader.load("savedjson.json", function (obj){

        obj.traverse(function(child){ initChild(child); });

        scene.add(obj);
    }
```

In initChild(child) I do this:

```
    initChild(child)
    {
        if(child.material != null)
        {
           var childMaterialName = child.material.name;
           child.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
           child.material.name = childMaterialName ;
           AssignMap(child.material);
        }
    }
```

In AssignMap(material) I first load the textures, then assign them based on the material name:

```
    AssignMap(material)
    {
        var texture_metal = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("media/texture_metal.jpg");
        var texture_glass = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("media/texture_glass.jpg");

        if(material.name == "metal texture")
        {
            material.map = texture_metal;
        }

        if(material.name == "glass texture")
        {
           material.map = texture_glass;
        }
    }
```

Comment: on the SceneExporter there is some function to export the textures, but it doesn't working well, all the textures are defined as undefined, anyway thanks for the answer, i will check on it

Comment: Here is the where I asked much the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25060317/when-using-three-objectloader-if-the-model-has-more-than-one-texture-how-do-i